# Remembering positions when deleting entries in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I am creating a card game which should have the following functionality:

1. 3 Cards gets on the board on position 0, 1 and 2 -> [0][1][2]
2. The user can pick one of the cards
3. The chosen card needs to be removed, and the remaining two cards needs to move a position higher. Then a new card should be added to position 0.

Examples ([X] is an empty/non existing card):

- User picks card on position 2 -> [0][1][2]
- User picks card on position 0 -> [0][X][2][3]
- User picks card on position 1 -> [0][1][X][3]

The idea is that whenever a card hits position 5, no other cards but that can be chosen. I am a bit lost of how to create this, so I'd appreciate any help.

I currently got the following code to add a card to the board:

```
 function addCardToBoard() {
    let curCard = myDeck.getCard();
    let cardHtml = "<div class='card'>" + curCard.category + "<br>" + curCard.method + "</div>";
    $(cardHtml).prependTo("#cards").on("click", function() { 
        $(this).remove();
        clickCard(curCard); 
    });
}
```

and a method `function clickCard(myCard){}` to discover a click on a certain card.

Comment: Looks like Dux and Seb are in the same class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422581/creating-an-array-with-unicode-in-js-deck-of-cards#53422581

Comment: I don't believe that it is the same problem at all. But if it is, I doubt we are, since this is a personal project besides all studies :)

Comment: The coincidence of timing was funny. I really did that so you would have a reference to each others work. May help, may not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the issue. Creating an array and adding the elements and then sending further the index of the card instead of the card itself.

```
function addCardToBoard() {
        let curCard = myDeck.getCard();
        cardsArray.unshift(curCard);
        let cardHtml = "<div class='card'>" + curCard.category + "<br>" + curCard.method + "</div>";
        $(cardHtml).prependTo("#cards").on("click", function() { 
            $(this).remove();
            clickCard(cardsArray.indexOf(curCard)); 
        });
    }
```